# Usb4java alternate setting

Tags: java, usb4java

I have a device, with which I have to communicate with, through USB.

It has 1 active configuration, that has 1 interface.

The interface has more alternate settings (IDLE, PROF1, PROF2). By default IDLE is active.

My question is, that how can I make the PROF2 setting active?

```
bNumConfigurations:   0x01
bNumInterfaces:       0x01

[IDLE]
bInterfaceNumber:     0x00
bAlternateSetting:    0x00

[PROF1]
bInterfaceNumber:     0x00
bAlternateSetting:    0x01

[PROF2]
bInterfaceNumber:     0x00
bAlternateSetting:    0x02
```

Code...

```
UsbConfiguration config = (UsbConfiguration) device.getActiveUsbConfiguration();    
UsbInterface iface = config.getUsbInterface((byte)0x00);    
UsbInterface alt = iface.getSetting((byte)0x02);                // <= Setting is not active.
UsbEndpoint endpoint = alt.getUsbEndpoint((byte)0x83);    
UsbPipe pipe = endpoint.getUsbPipe();    
pipe.open();                                                    // <= Pipe is not active.
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier for us if you tell us what library you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem here is that the high-level API simply doesn't provide a way to set either the active configuration or the alternate setting to something other than default.

The low level API does though... here's what I used::

```
// Iterate over the devices using low-level API to match a device + config combo from a high-level API
DeviceList list = new DeviceList();
LibUsb.getDeviceList(null, list);
for (Device d : list) {
    DeviceDescriptor descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
    LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(d, descriptor);
    if (descriptor.idVendor() == device.getUsbDeviceDescriptor().idVendor() &&
            descriptor.idProduct() == device.getUsbDeviceDescriptor().idProduct()) {
        Context context = new Context();
        LibUsb.init(context);
        DeviceHandle handle = new DeviceHandle();
        LibUsb.open(d, handle);
        LibUsb.setConfiguration(handle, 0x02); // or cfg.getUsbConfigurationDescriptor().bConfigurationValue()
        LibUsb.setInterfaceAltSetting(handle, 0x00, 0x02);
        LibUsb.claimInterface(handle, ifc);    // valid test, can't claim unless active
        LibUsb.releaseInterface(handle, ifc);
        LibUsb.close(handle);
        LibUsb.exit(context);
        return; // break, etc
    }
}
LibUsb.freeDeviceList(list, true); // usually in a finally block
```

When placed in a helper function, this logic should be valid for setting the active configuration.

According to the `libusb` devs, the configuration will remain active so as long as the device isn't unplugged.  This is per https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/158#issuecomment-190501281.

Finally, if you're not doing it already, I recommend setting DEBUG via command line `LIBUSB_DEBUG=4` to get the raw output from `libusb`.  This helped considerably in my troubleshooting efforts.  In this case you should see something along the lines of:

```
[21.987087] [0000d903] libusb: debug [libusb_set_configuration] configuration 2
```